# phpMailer SMTP working in one setup, but not another (SMTP 535 Incorrect authentication data)

Tags: php, apache, smtp, phpmailer

PHPMailer from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/

In my 'offline' WAMP setup (localhost), my PHP file using PHPMailer via Gmail works perfectly (after I remembered to switch on php_openssl). This suggests my PHP code and Gmail setup is correct.

However on my 'online' hosting provider, I get "ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data ".

535 suggests incorrect password, but it's the identical file that's been uploaded. I therefore believe it's a server config issue, but have no idea where to start. I've compared phpinfo(), and openSSL is enabled on both - any suggestions?

Comment: OK - I've found that it does sometimes work, and sometimes not - no code change, just intermittent. I'm definitely not hitting Gmail's 500 quota and the error coming back is about password, which isn't being changed.

Comment: can you say which one is your hosting provider? i have not such problems using hostgator (to discard that it might be server side error)

Answer (score 0):

just an idea, but maybe you have special characters in your password and that is why it does not match? In addition you might want to try to use your local php.ini to ensure that it is not a problem, just for a second of course

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be as you describe an environment issue. Probably you 'online' (or production) hosting is more secure than your localhost environment. Some kind of firewall might be blocking you from connecting to outbound sockets/ports. Pretty usual pratice with outbound SMTP ports.

For checking if this is your problem, test which ports are available. You've a bunch of methods to do that.

**Netstat**

```
netstat -l -t -p
```

**Php**

```
$p = fsockopen( '127.0.0.1', <port number>, $errno, $errstr, 5 );
if ( !$p )
    // port is closed or blocked
else
    // port is open and available
    fclose( $p );
```

**Python**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import * 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    target = raw_input('Enter host to scan: ')
    targetIP = gethostbyname(target)
    print 'Scanning on host ', targetIP

    for i in range(20, 1025):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

        result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

        if(result == 0) :
            print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i,)
        s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your remote host isn't configured with reverse DNS or the IP address could be rate limited based on a value from [SenderBase](http://www.senderbase.org)/alike.

The intermittent displays of the issue would rule out an issue like routing or your physical credentials or firewall. It would put the issue more in the hands of, rate limiting, quality of service, etc.

Check SenderBase above for the host which is not working, see if it has a poor rating. I bet the host that IS working has a great score or isn't listed at all.